# Getting array from multidimensional array having maximum lead_id(any particular variable)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

So here is my array

```
x=[['56','xyz','xyz@gmail.com','123456789'],['623','yzx','yzx@gmail.com','95134786'],['901','dvjs','dvjs@yahoo.in','945678123']]
```

How i can select an array having highest first index i.e in this case result should be

```
['901','dvjs','dvjs@yahoo.in','945678123']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a specified key:

```
>>> x=[['56','xyz','xyz@gmail.com','123456789'],['623','yzx','yzx@gmail.com','95134786'],['901','dvjs','dvjs@yahoo.in','945678123']]
>>> 
>>> selection = max(x, key=lambda item: int(item[0]))
>>> selection
['901', 'dvjs', 'dvjs@yahoo.in', '945678123']
```